# How to map dictionary to object of specific class?

Tags: dictionary, mapping, smalltalk, pharo

I have a given dictionary and want to map it to an object of a specific class.
All keys of the dictionary should be mapped to equally named instance variables of the object.

I guess this is a common procedure? What is the common way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider doing something like this:

```
dict := { #x -> 5 . #y -> 6 } asDictionary. "dictionary as you described"
basicObj := Point basicNew. "basic instance of your object"

dict keysAndValuesDo: [ :key :val |
    basicObj instVarNamed: key put: val ].

^ basicObj
```

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed a common pattern. It is often used in serialization and materialization. You can find an implementation in 
[STON](https://github.com/svenvc/ston)